# Install windows7 and ubuntu 14.04 on a computer which already has windows and ubuntu 12.04 installed

Tags: windows-7, grub, ubuntu-12.04, windows-installation, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed windows 7 and ubuntu 12.04 in 2 separate partitions in my machine and I can access both using the GRUB. Now I want to re-install windows 7 and ubuntu 14.04 to my machine. What is the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: If you just wish to reinstall both OS's to 2 partitions again but with 14.04 and not 12.04 you should be able to do this the same way as before with grub. To install 14.04 over the 12.02 partition and leave windows 7 as is and also run with grub it should also be able to be done with or without a 3rd party software option. Someone with some more time or you after checking 14.04 Ubuntu install doc's at Ask Ubuntu [stackechange] or the ubuntu download page can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

First back up all your data from both OS.

Install Windows 7 first. It will overwrite the MBR and Ubuntu 12.04's boot entry will be lost.

Now install Ubuntu 14.04. Ubuntu will automatically add Windows 7's boot entry in the GRUB boot loader when it will detect its presence.

Comment: After installing Windows 7, will the partition in which I previously installed ubuntu 12.04 still be there? I should install ubuntu 14.04 on that same partition, am I correct?

Comment: @user463659 : Yes it will be there. Only thing is that since its boot entry will be removed you won't be able to access it. And yes you can reuse that existing Ubuntu partition to install Ubuntu 14.04. There is no point of wasting the space and I guess you won't be needing two different versions of Ubuntu, right?

Comment: Yes, I don't need 2 different versions. But when I install windows 7 the GRUB will be corrupted right? Then when I install ubuntu 14.04, will it come out fine?

Comment: Not corrupted it will be overwritten by Windows. When you will be installing Ubuntu 14.04 then it will install the GRUB boot loader again which will include the Windows boot entry in it after checking the system and it will be your default boot loader.